# В строке все символы заменить на знак !, как сделать через while?

Tags: c

```
char str[80] =  "gre qg1 256g#r4 6c aegev e gea, =2g +rd*gf g3t523gr"; //строка.
char digits[11] = "0123456789"; //строка цифр   
char S =  '!';

printf("%s\n", str);

char *p = str;
char *d = digits;

//через массив.
// Тут все работает
for (int i = 0; p[i]; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; d[j]; ++j){
        if (p[i] == d[j])
            str[i] = S;
    }
}   

//через While как. ???  

while (*p){
    while (*d){
        if (*p == *d)
            *p = S;
        ++d;
    }
    ++p;
}
printf("%s\n", p);
```

Comment: Через индексирование всё работает, помогите  через while

Comment: Определитесь: C или C++. Пока к C++ ваш код не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: 1) Даже не вникая в алгоритм с while - в этой точке у вас `p` указывает на последний символ строки, стало быть, ничего и не выводится: `cout << p;` 2) Прошагайте ваш код в отладчике и всё увидите своими глазами, и это, и вторую ошибку.

Comment: Я плохо понимаю while

Comment: Так и не должно, во-первых, `cout << p;` ничего не выведет, потому-что `p` уже указывает на конец; во-вторых по `d` проходит **только** первый раз. Вы же на начало не ставите указатель. Перед внутренним вайлом поставить `d = digits;` и в конце выводить не `p`, а `str` и будет счастье.

Comment: вы должны восстанавливать начальное значение `d` после каждой итерации внешнего цикла.

Comment: В общем, в таком крохотном кусочке как минимум две ошибки, один забытый break (правда, принципиально ни на что не влияющий), и до кучи - неиспользование `isdigit()`, что сократило бы кол-во плюх до одной. Ну и стандартное: упорное нежелание загрузить код в отладчик и проверить как на самом деле он работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так ещё лучше:

```
p = str; // !!!
while(*p)
{
    if( isdigit(*p) ) *p = '!';
    p++;
}
cout << str; // !!!
```

Ну или так:

```
while(*p)
{
    if( strchr(d,*p) ) *p = '!';
    p++;
}
```

Comment: Для меня, как для чайника это ещё друдно

Comment: Это **проще** вашего кода.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать:

```
while (*p){
    d = digits;
    while (*d){
        if (*p == *d){
            *p = S;
            break;
        }
        ++d;
    }
    ++p;
}
cout << str;
```

Comment: Объясни почему Вы  d = digits; вместили в while?

Comment: Прошагайте оба варианта (ваш и с исправлениями) в отладчике и увидите всё своими глазами.

Comment: Потому что по вашему получается бесконечное наращивание d.

Comment: А вообще эффективнее просто проверять '0' <= *p && *p <= '9'

Comment: получается тогда и строка с цифрами не нужна, верно?

Comment: Вам выше привели хороший вариант